# SceneKit custom geometry .. SCNGeometrySource with 16-bit integers

Tags: scenekit

Using SceneKit to build some large custom geometries, in order to keep array sizes as small as possible, I fed SCNGeometrySource with vectors with (x,y,z) as short (Int16) integers, as follows:

```
    let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(data: dataContent!,
        semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex, vectorCount: 4960,
        floatComponents: false, componentsPerVector: 3, bytesPerComponent: 2,
        dataOffset: 0, dataStride: 6)
```

.. however, this data was not acceptable, generating the error:

```
SceneKit: error, C3DMeshSourceGetValueAtIndexAsVector3 - Type not supported
```

**Question**: What forms of vector components does SceneKit support?

After writing this question I'm going to try trial & error to see what happens with triples and quads of Float32, Int32, etc.  I know Float64 does work but I don't need better than ±2^15 precision, so why waste memory?  Perhaps someone can provide a definitive answer .. Apple's documentation appears to not do so.

Comment: For what it's worth: `Int32` fails, `Float32` works empirically